# Encircled i as custom item label gives me a "missing }" error

Tags: tikz-pgf, itemize

I want to define a custom item label, which can be used in an unordered list and should look like an "info" symbol. It should be a lowercase letter 'i' inside a circle.

What I did:

```
\documentclass[draft,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\info}{\item[%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt]{i};
  \end{tikzpicture}
]}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \info{info}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

It gives me the following errors:

```
/main.tex:90: Argument of \tikz@fig@scan@options has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.90   \info
          {info}
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
draw,circle,inner sep=1pt
./main.tex:90: Paragraph ended before \tikz@fig@scan@options was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.90   \info
          {info}
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

./main.tex:90: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<recently read> }
 
l.90   \info
          {info}
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

./main.tex:90: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\sbox  ...box {\color@setgroup #2\color@endgroup }
                                                  
l.90   \info
          {info}
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

./main.tex:90: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endpgfpicture ...globally \endgroup \hss \egroup 
                                                  \pgf@restore@layerlist@fro...
l.90   \info
          {info}
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

./main.tex:90: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.90   \info
          {info}
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

./main.tex:90: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endpgfpicture ...dpicture \endgroup \hss \egroup 
                                                  \pgfsys@typesetpicturebox ...
l.90   \info
          {info}
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

./main.tex:90: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.90   \info
          {info}
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.


./main.tex:91: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.91 \end{itemize}
                
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


./main.tex:91: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.91 \end{itemize}
                
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


./main.tex:91: LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.91 \end{itemize}
                
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


./main.tex:91: LaTeX Error: \begin{tikzpicture} on input line 90 ended by \end{itemize}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.91 \end{itemize}
                
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

Followed by some other errors.

I really don't see where I should have missed a '}'. Does this error occur because it is inside the item label option?

Comment: Why don't you use `enumerate`?

Comment: You need to but braces around the optional argument to `\item`. Right now LaTeX is reading up to the **first** closing `]` and treating it as the end of the optional argument, so it is processing `\item[\begin{tikzpicture}\node[...1pt]` with the incomplete code as its argument.

Comment: Regarding the previous comment, do you consider your question answered, or do you still wait for improvement?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to continue using `itemize` and to customize the item symbol.

```
\documentclass[draft,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\info}{
\raisebox{-1pt}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt]{i};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[\info] Hello
  \item[\info] What are you looking for?
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:
[image: custom TikZ itemize]

### EDIT

If you want to align correctly the `i` into the circle and your text, you could do the following:

```
\documentclass[draft,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\info}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(content.base)]
    \node[draw,circle,minimum width=5pt]{};
    \node(content){i};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[\info] Hello
  \item[\info] What are you looking for?
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

which produces:
[image: v2]